# Jackrabbit, saving a lot of documents too slow

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I am using jackrabbit for several projects as a document repository and it was working pretty well, but I'm having problems with one system in particular, let me describe the situation:

- By slow I mean from 40 seconds to about 2 minutes.
- I am saving pdf documents each one is about 100kb in size.
- I generate about 20 documents in a minute.
- Each document is saved in it's own session.
- This only happens under load, when I generate a single document it is saved in seconds.
- Lookup is fast enough, taking just a few seconds.

I don't know a lot about jackrabbit internals, but I think it might be the lucene indexing what's taking so long.

So, is it possible to fine tune something to get a better time?

Comment: what [PersistenceManager](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ) are you using to store JCR documents? (local filesystem, remote fs, database, etcc..)

Comment: I'm using a local filesystem every filesystem is a org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem

Comment: ohh for the persistencemanager i'm using derby org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.DerbyPersistenceManager with a local db

Comment: When you say 40 seconds, do you mean the time taken for each PDF increases from "saved in seconds" to 40 seconds?

Comment: I would probably get a few full thread dumps to check what's going on.

Comment: Yes, when there's a single document generated it takes 2~3 seconds, when there are several documents, it takes at least 40 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at the following docs to make sure your configuration is appropriate:

- http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore about how/where binary files are stored
- http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/IndexingConfiguration about indexing configuration

40 seconds to two minutes to store a 100kb PDF is much more than what I'd expect - of course you'll also need to check your environment and make sure there's no disk swapping or other basic system problem that's causing this.